# Where to find TideSDK sdk for windows?

Tags: tidesdk

I've an older project using TideSDK to maintain. But, when I upgraded my mac to El Capitan, I lost my VM containing the SDK (file corrupted error with virtual box).

And now the TideSDK project has shut down and it is impossible to download this SDK again.

Has someone a backup of the SDK file? The exact filename is TideSDK-1.3.1-beta-win-x86.zip

Thanks a lot for your help !

Michael

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've added the sdk for windows and macOs in my fork of TideSDK, you can find them here :  https://github.com/zedissime/TideSDK (TideSDK/downloads/sdk/windows/TideSDK-1.3.1-beta-win-x86.zip)

Comment: Thanks you save my day!